# Celery-Django: Unable to execute tasks asynchronously

Tags: python, django, celery

I'm trying to run some tasks in the background while users browse my site, but whenever I call a function using Celery it seems to be executed synchronously instead of asynchronously.

e.g., when I call function.delay() the entire site hangs until function.delay() returns. Other methods of calling functions in a similar manner (apply_async, subtasks) exhibit the same problem.

I'm guessing something in either Django or Celery is misconfigured, but I don't know what it is.

Celery configuration in settings.py:

```
import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()

CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "amqp"
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = "djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler"
BROKER_HOST = "localhost"
BROKER_PORT = 5672
BROKER_USER = "test"
BROKER_PASSWORD = "test"
BROKER_VHOST = "testhost"

TEST_RUNNER = "djcelery.contrib.test_runner.run_tests"

CELERY_IMPORTS = ("myapp.tasks",)

BROKER_BACKEND = "memory"
CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = True
```

Trying to start the Celery daemon with "./manage.py celeryd", I get the following output:

```
[2011-09-23 09:25:38,026: WARNING/MainProcess]  

 -------------- celery@iMac.local v2.2.7
---- **** -----
--- * ***  * -- [Configuration]
-- * - **** ---   . broker:      memory://test@localhost:5672/testhost
- ** ----------   . loader:      djcelery.loaders.DjangoLoader
- ** ----------   . logfile:     [stderr]@WARNING
- ** ----------   . concurrency: 4
- ** ----------   . events:      OFF
- *** --- * ---   . beat:        OFF
-- ******* ----
--- ***** ----- [Queues]
 --------------   . celery:      exchange:celery (direct) binding:celery


[2011-09-23 09:25:38,035: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@iMac.local has started.
```

Comment: What web server are you using?

Comment: I'm currently running off localhost with the default Django setup. Planning on using Apache once I get things off the ground.

Comment: Hmm, provide your celery related configuration then and describe to us how do you start celery deamon.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what a lot of these configuration settings do. This project was sort of dumped in my lap in a semi-working state a few weeks back (and I had no experience with Django, Celery, or even Python beforehand). I'm only now starting to find some things that aren't quite working right.

Answer (score 8):

Try removing

```
CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = True
```

You are explicitly asking celery to execute tasks synchronously. It'll always wait for the result.
This setting is useful for writing unit tests etc.

Read http://ask.github.com/celery/configuration.html